# Is not the getnode() number constant?

Tags: python, uuid

I was trying to generate a special kind of serial number for a computer by using the `getnode()` number.

```
from uuid import getnode

gnd = str(getnode())
serial = "UMH{}F-{}3{}T4-M3{}I7-0{}A{}W".format(gnd[10], gnd[3], gnd[13], gnd[0], gnd[4], gnd[6])
```

I noticed today that the `getnode()` method gives a different number value than a few weeks ago.

I use the same computer and I did not make any changes to the hardware! However, if the number I get from the `getnode()` method is not constant, this will crash the whole scenario.

Any clue?

Comment: I have no idea how `getnode` works but you probably should at very least mention your __operation system__ for example is it _Linux_? Your Q has a higher chance if you go crazy with details.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting. It is Windows

Answer (score 0):

If you have multiple network interfaces on the machine, it may return any one it finds.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/uuid.html

Comment: My computer is not connected to a network other than the internet. But it's too dangerous for my scenario if getnode () has such a property of variability. :(
Is there any other way to get an id that is unique to each computer?

Comment: @scan tried a MAC address? Associate all MACs on one device with each other; this way it doesn't matter which one you happen to get this time.

Comment: TÜRKÇE
İNGILIZCE

I used the number retrieved with the getNode () method. but after a while I gave it a different number and my serial became useless. What is the way of what you say? which method should I use?